# "I am loving you" vs "I love you"

Tags: present-tense

In famous song [Still loving you](http://www.lyricsfreak.com/s/scorpions/still+loving+you_20122510.html) it is said, that "I am loving you". Is it expressed in present continuous tense or not?
And if it is, then shouldn't it be in present simple?

Comment: An interesting paper (Solveig Granath and Michael Wherrity): [*I’m loving you–and knowing it too*: Aspect and so-called stative verbs](http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:704600/FULLTEXT01.pdf).

Comment: Why would someone writing a love song give a flying fig about grammar? Do songwriters in your first language write in perfect sentences? I should hope not; it would make for rather dull music.